# Why can I exclude servlet-api from endpoints-framework but not from endpoints-management-control-appengine-all?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, servlets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

[endpoints-management-control-appengine-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-management-control-appengine-all/1.0.12)

[endpoints-framework](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-framework/2.2.1)

Both of these packages come with some version of `servlet-api-2.5.jar`/`servlet-api` dependency

```xml
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
```

### Without any exclusions

```sh
2020-07-16 01:22:48.113  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextExcepti
on: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-07-16 01:22:48.127  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-16 01:22:48.130 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/app/libs/servlet-api-2.5.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/libs/endpoints-management-control-appengine-all-1.0.12.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/libs/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext: file:/app/libs/servlet-api-2.5.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

### With one exclusion

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [START api_management] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [END api_management] -->
```

(Exact same as above)

## With other exclusion

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [START api_management] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [END api_management] -->
```

```sh
2020-07-16 01:25:49.509  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextExcepti
on: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-07-16 01:25:49.524  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-16 01:25:49.529 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/app/libs/endpoints-management-control-appengine-all-1.0.12.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/libs/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext: file:/app/libs/endpoints-management-control-appengine-all-1.0.12.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

### With both exclusions

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [START api_management] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [END api_management] -->
```

(same as above)

So we can conclude that exclusions simply aren't working for endpoints-management-control-appengine-all.

I have no idea how to fix this? There has got to be some weird quirk going on.

Obviously the goal is to remove all outdated transitive servlet dependencies so that `jar:file:/app/libs/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class` can be auto-selected, which probably has the new virtualization method, as recommended by answers like [An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909834/an-attempt-was-made-to-call-a-method-that-does-not-exist-sts).

### To test these exclusions I am creating a docker container with google jib plugin and docker run

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <to>
                        <image>gcr.io/${endpoints.project.id}/endpoints-container</image>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

`PORT=8080 && docker run --rm -p 9090:${PORT} -e PORT=${PORT} gcr.io/project-id/endpoints-container`

I'm not sure whether this detail is relevant, but something I did notice was that **endpoints-management-control-appengine-all** has a different package structure, with respect to the way javax servlet 2.5 is included compared to **endpoints-framework**.

#### included alongside `com` which doesnt happen in endpoints-framework

[image]

Comment: Where you able to fix this issue? And if so, how?

Comment: haven't touched this project for months, so no unfortunately @CodeJ